# Dictionary observation space Acme DQN agent

Tags: tensorflow, reinforcement-learning, agent, dqn, acme-deepmind

I'm trying to add illegal action masking to my *dqn agent* using [masked_epsilon_greedy](https://github.com/deepmind/acme/blob/master/acme/tf/networks/masked_epsilon_greedy.py).
Does anyone know how can I update the policy network to use `observation["your_key_for_observation"]` rather than *'observation'* since the observation space is a dictionary containing both the observations and legal actions?

Answer (score 0):

the answer is adding `lambda inputs: inputs["your_key_for_observation"]` to the network in case someone encounters this issue in the future.